# Pivot based on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The data might look like this:

| ID | UID | GID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| A | 12 | 3 |

And I would like the destination to look like this :

| ID | UID1 | UID2 | GID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aa | 1 | 12 | 3 |

Comment: What happens if you have 3 rows for `'A'`? Why did it's value change from `'A'` to `'Aa'`?

Comment: I have only 2 rows per group

Comment: In your example, yes, but I'm asking if you *could* have more.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `ID` and `GID` are the grouping columns, something like this:

```sql
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT ID,
           UID,
           GID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,GID ORDER BY UID) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT UPPER(ID) + LOWER(ID) AS ID,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN UID END) AS UID1,
       MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN UID END) AS UID2,
       GID
FROM RNs
GROUP BY ID,
         GID;
```

This, of course, won't scale if you have 3+ UIDs.

Answer (score 2):

If you have many pivot columns, then `ROW_NUMBER` is your best bet. But since you say you are guaranteed always two rows, there is one shorter option:

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    MIN(UID) AS UID1,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN MAX(UID) END AS UID2,
    GID
from CTE
GROUP BY ID, GID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [ID]) AS Rn FROM yourtable
)
select 
    ID,
    MAX(case when RN = 1 then UID end) UID1,
    MAX(case when RN = 2 then UID end) UID2,
    GID
from CTE
GROUP BY ID,GID
```